# Angular Dart 2 - querySelect returning null

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to set up a drag&drop component to upload multiple files. However, when I attempt to access elements on the DOM with the `querySelector` method, I end up with `null`.

I've tried to implement the `AfterViewInit` class to no avail. Here's my current dart code for the component:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:dnd/dnd.dart';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';


@Component(
  selector: 'upload',
  templateUrl: 'upload.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'upload.css'
  ]

)
class Upload implements AfterViewInit {

 @override
 void ngAfterViewInit() {
   // TODO: implement ngOnInit
   Draggable d = new Draggable(document.querySelectorAll('.page'), avatarHandler :  new AvatarHandler.clone());

   var del = document.querySelector('.upload');

   print(del); //prints null

   Dropzone dropzone = new Dropzone(document.querySelector('.upload')); //throws an error, as it doesn't expect null.

   dropzone.onDrop.listen((DropzoneEvent event){
     print(event);
   });

 }

}
```

Also, my upload.html file is as follows:

```
<div class="center-me page" uk-grid>
   <div class="uk-align-center text-align-center">
     <h2 class="text-align-center" >Upload a file</h2>
     <div class="upload uk-placeholder uk-text-center">
       <span uk-icon="icon: cloud-upload"></span>
      <span class="uk-text-middle">Attach binaries by dropping them here or</span>
    <div uk-form-custom>
      <input type="file" multiple>
      <span class="uk-link">selecting one</span>
    </div>
  </div>

   <progress id="progressbar" class="uk-progress" value="0" max="100" hidden></progress>

   </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this looks like it should work. I wouldn't actually suggest doing it this way as it will get any element with an upload class which if you reuse the component will be a lot.

I would suggest using the ViewChild syntax instead

```
class Upload implements AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild('upload')
 void uploadElm(HtmlElement elm) {
   Dropzone dropzone = new Dropzone(elm);
   dropzone.onDrop.listen((DropzoneEvent event){
     print(event);
   });
 }
}
```

In the template:

```
<div class="uk-placeholder uk-text-center" #upload>
```

That said you shouldn't be getting null from the querySelect, but from the code you have shown I'm not sure why.

Comment: Hey @Ted, thanks for the reply. I've tried to implement this code but it seems the `uploadElm` method is never called by the class.

Comment: Something else is going on then. Which makes your question make more sense if you look in the Dom is the div even loaded?

Comment: Your code does work! Thanks. I'm still not sure why the `querySelector` was/is returning null, but this seems like a great replacement.